# How to return the value of a variable to the previous class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I pass isSendEmail boolean variable to another AboutPageWidget widget, in this widget I change the value of this variable and I want it to return to screen 1, how to do that, how to get the value of isSendEmail variable on screen 1?

**screen 1**

```
Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    AboutPageWidget(isSendEmail: isSendEmail),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 42,
                    ),
                    isSendEmail
                        ? SetNewPasswordFields(
                            newPasswordCubit: newPasswordCubit,
                          )
                        : const EmailFieldWidget(),
                  ],
                ),
```

**screen 2**

```
class AboutPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AboutPageWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.isSendEmail,
  }) : super(key: key);

  bool isSendEmail;

  @override
  State<AboutPageWidget> createState() => _AboutPageWidgetState();
}

class _AboutPageWidgetState extends State<AboutPageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => widget.isSendEmail
                      ? setState(
                          () => widget.isSendEmail = !widget.isSendEmail,
                        )
                      : _onBackPressed(context),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a callback in the screen2 then listen to it on screen.

For example:

Screen1:

```dart
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
    AboutPageWidget(
        isSendEmail: isSendEmail,
        isSendEmailChanged: (value) => setState(() => isSendEmail = value); 
    ),
    const SizedBox(
        height: 42,
    ),
    isSendEmail
        ? SetNewPasswordFields(
            newPasswordCubit: newPasswordCubit,
            )
        : const EmailFieldWidget(),
    ],
),
```

Screen2:

```dart
class AboutPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AboutPageWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.isSendEmail,
    required this.isSendEmailChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  ValueChanged<bool> isSendEmailChanged;
  bool isSendEmail;

  @override
  State<AboutPageWidget> createState() => _AboutPageWidgetState();
}

class _AboutPageWidgetState extends State<AboutPageWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => widget.isSendEmail
                        ? widget.isSendEmailChanged(!widget.isSendEmail)
                        : _onBackPressed(context),
```

Then inside _AboutPageWidgetState whenever you want to emit that isSendEmail has changed, just call `widget.isSendEmailChanged` with the new value.

For more complex states, I'd recommend using Provider or some other state management solution.

Comment: That is, this ValueChanged means that when any variable with the bool type is changed, then its value will be saved here?

Comment: And how to change the value in widget.isSendEmailChanged? Just through the setState method?

Comment: Yup, that's what ValueChanged does, it's just a typedef that resolves to `void Function(T value)`, where the T generic will be the type you pass in `bool` in this case

Comment: I've updated the screen2 code with how to change the value, just replacing the setState() method call with `widget.isSendEmailChanged(!widget.isSendEmail)`

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works, now I will use this option!

Answer (score 2):

Navigater has a .then method so you can do

```
Navigator.of(context).push(nextscreen).then(result=>{
  // Result will contain the data you passed back
});
```

and on the next screen

```
Navigator.pop(variable);
```

Comment: I like this solution, if you're sharing state between screens I'd recommend this approach, if it's between regular widgets then my solution will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want your code to be really messy, It'd be much better to use simple state management. [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) should come in handy.